# MacBook pro mid 2014 with High Sierra and APFS - Overallocation Detected on main device

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, apfs

Can somebody explain what 'Overallocation' means in context of file system? I constantly see this message when trying to resize APFS partition, disk checks don't find any problems.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have the same problem. From /var/log/fsck_apfs.log:
** Checking the snap/dev/disk0s2: shots.
/dev/disk0s2: ** Verifying allocated space.
/dev/disk0s2: warning: Overallocation Detected on Main device: (1116392+1) bitmap address (802394)
/dev/disk0s2: ** The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK.
/dev/disk0s2: fsck_apfs completed at Tue Jan  2 18:20:46 2018
/dev/disk0s2:

Answer (score 2):

I would have commented on Peku2455's answer, but I don't have 50 rep. So here is the solution, based on Peku's answer (which is missing the -o switch to fix overallocation)

In Terminal in Recovery Mode (press Command+R while booting, select Utilities -> Terminal):

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
fsck_apfs -oy /dev/disk0
```

Comment: tried this solution and it resolved the issue on first try. What it comes down to is mac os isn't able to fix the disk while it is also in use.

Answer (score 1):

I booted in Recovery mode, open Terminal and run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0` and after that `fsck_apfs -y /dev/disk0`
After this all was fine
Maybe for you, the drive name is different, you can find it by running `diskutil list`